# onClick event not passing a function when placed in a forEach loop in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I need to display some HTML based on an event from a checkbox.
My onClick event on the parent node is not passing a function  when placed in a forEach loop [(here's my fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/1993/). The strange thing about it that it will pass a function when i pass it to a single element.

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {toggle: false}
  },
  handleClick : function(event){
    this.setState({toggle : !this.state.toggle});
  },
  render: function(){
    var checkboxes = [];
    this.props.data.forEach(
      function(name)
      {
        checkboxes.push(<CheckBox onClick={this.handleClick} name={name} />);
                        });
        var textBox = this.state.toggle ? <InputBox name="Bar" /> : null;
        return (
          <div>
          <CheckBox name="Foo" onClick={this.handleClick} />
          {checkboxes}
          {textBox}
          </div>
        );
      }
});
```

Does anyone know why this is happening ? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` in `this.handleClick` [no longer refers to the React component object](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/), because it's inside an anonymous function passed to forEach. In general you can `bind` a function's `this` to that of its context, like this

```
this.props.data.forEach(
  function(name) { ... }.bind(this));
```

With forEach, you can also just pass it as a second argument.

```
this.props.data.forEach(
  function(name) { ... }, this);
```

Comment: `this` is actually undefined, or the global object in non-strict mode in the forEach callback.

Comment: `forEach` takes an optional second argument as the `this` context, no need to call `bind`: `this.props.data.forEach(function() { ... }, this);`

Comment: Oops, I guess I still have more to learn about `this`. Edited my original answer. I left the bind example in because it may be useful to know for similar situations where passing `this` as an argument isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you could pass "this" context object into the body of your anonymous function by using of helper variable "_self", for example:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {toggle: false}
    },
    handleClick : function(event){
        this.setState({toggle : !this.state.toggle});
    },
    render: function(){
        var checkboxes = [];
        var _self = this;
        this.props.data.forEach(
        function(name)
        {
            checkboxes.push(<CheckBox onClick={_self.handleClick} name={name} />);
        });
        var textBox = _self.state.toggle ? <InputBox name="Bar" /> : null;
        return (
        <div>
            <CheckBox name="Foo" onClick={_self.handleClick} />
            {checkboxes}
            {textBox}
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```